# access and remove element from $data array codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a associative array $data['arr1'] which is populated by a query. I need to iterate through the array , check each record for a specific value, and if the record is present , remove that record from the array. Here is my code:

```
    foreach($data['arr1'] as $key => $row) {

        // code for checking the value in a record. Cannot access the element here. I have 
           tried to print with these statements
        echo $data['arr1'] -> Firstname;
        echo $data['arr1'] [0];
        echo $data['arr1'][$key];
        echo [$key]; // gives me the values of index 0,1,2,3

        if(//check is true)
        {
            unset($data['arr1'][$key]);  //works fine, removes elements as needed
        }

    }
```

How can I access the element for checks? I think it is a combination of `data['arr1']` and `$key` but i cannot find a correct combination. Also when I do `print_r($data['arr1'])` it prints the whole array correctly. as:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 107 [assessmentTime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00  [Gender] => 1 [DOB] => 2009-05-06 12:00:00 [Village] => Bhains [Tehsil] => 1 [UnionCouncil] => 2 [Snap] => 582864.jpg  [WhyWeDisable] => [HasDeleted] => 0 [CallerID] => 0 [vTime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [CaseId] => 98 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 57 [FirstName] => ..............
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to remove one element from the array??

Comment: yes, and the element is removed fine. But i need to access that element before removing it, And I cannot do it

Comment: first of all dont use echo on arrays, use print_r($array), var_export($array), or var_dump( $array ); but before these do echo '<pre>'; for formatting, so echo '<pre>'; var_export($data);

Comment: prin_r($array) prints the whole array in one go. I need to print each record separately. How I do that?

Comment: print_r($array[$key]); unless it say stdclass, then it is an object and you use ->  So you do  print_r($data[0]->id); to get the id, basically print_r($data[0]); or print_r($data[1]); gets the object, then you access its property as standard with the arrow ->

Comment: $data['childs'][0] -> id worked. Thank you very much . :)

Comment: You're are accessing an array of object not a pure array @Kulfi

Comment: @uchiha yes. that was my mistake. the correct way was $data['arr'][index] -> id;

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach( $data as $obj ){
  echo $obj->id;
  ..etc.
}
```

You are confusing an array of objects with a multi-dimensional array.

or you can output them manually as

```
echo $data[0]->id;
```

If you only need to look at say the first one.

Anyway the give away here is this bit, when you print the whole array out.

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (
```

See where it says object.  Arrays we access with `[ key ]` objects we access with `$obj->property`.